# how can i make clickable phone link in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile

my site uses javascript so that when a user clicks a store, a popup with the store info shows up. the store's website and address are clickable but i cant get the same code to work for the phone number

the website code is a bit longer but below is the code for the phone link and the email link. the email link works but not the phone

```
if(v.telephone != '') {
    info_window_string += "<p class='tel'>"+v.titletel+": <a href= 'tel:"+v.telephone"'>"+v.telephone+"</a></p>";
}

if(v.email != '') {
    info_window_string += "<p class='email'>"+v.titleemail+": <a href='mailto:"+v.email+"'>"+v.email+"</a></p>";
}
```

i expect that if i open the site in mobile and click the phone link, it'd put it in the phone number field ready to call

Comment: Does adding a `+` make a difference? `...<a href= 'tel:+"+v.telephone"'...` what is the telephone number pattern? `555-555-5555` or `5555555555`?

Comment: You miss '+' in tel href
<a href= 'tel:"+v.telephone**+**"'>"+v.telephone+"</a>

Comment: @epascarello that worked. tyvm!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing an `+` at the end of the `href`.

Solution:

```
"<p class='tel'>"+v.titletel+": <a href= 'tel:"+v.telephone+"'>"+v.telephone+"</a></p>"
```

Please try it.

Comment: Quote order is completely irrelevant, but the plus is important but already mentioned in the comments

Comment: Thats my fault sorry was thinking in other perpouses of the quotes no need in this case, will edit it out